# Applying for a Schengen visa after overstaying in the UK

Tags: schengen-visas

I previously overstayed my UK visa for two years. But I left voluntarily, no stamp on it, no ban and no deportation. It was 4 years ago. Last year I applied for a UK visitor visa. It was rejected and I did not appeal. Now I need to visit the Netherlands for a business visit. Will my Schengen visa application get rejected? Please advise.

Comment: The UK is not in the Schengen area. I'm not familiar with applying for a Schengen visa (Dutch so I don't need one) but unless they ask for this information specifically one has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: Please understand that your overstay and subsequent refusal (likely b/c of the previous visa violation, the failure to depart when you should have, and you possibly had no right to appeal the decision) are part of your UK immigration record

Comment: The chances of you getting a Schengen visa once you admit (or they find out your UK overstay) are slim to none. That's the reality.

Comment: Practically none of what you will write will be take seriously (just 4 years ago you demonstrated that you lied to immigration authorities). So you will need to have strong external proofs. So it is difficult, but not impossible.

Comment: I have been asked by my remote company to visit their office and to work with them for two weeks. Don't you think this will be a strong point for me and in the visa application, they have not ask for about previous overstay details. Do I need to mention regardless of what is in the application? UK is not part of the Schengen countries. Do you think they can easily pick up my overstay without looking into detail?

Comment: @Musonius Rufus I got the visa, Thanks for all your inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *automatic* ban.

However, you will be asked questions about prior visas, both Schengen and non-Schengen. You must answer truthfully that you overstayed in the UK and were subsequently refused a UK visa. Yes, this will decrease your chance of getting a Schengen visa. But lying and being discovered will nullify your chance of a Schengen visa.

The best course of action might be not to ask for a visa right now. If in 10 years time you have to explain one refused visa, it might be seen as an one-off incident, but if you have to explain two refused visas for both the UK and Schengen, it starts to look like a pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the Schengen visa application, there is no place that they have asked for about previous overstay. Do you think I still need to be mentioned about my previous overstay even though they did not ask in the application? Do I need to send the previous letter for visa refusal?

Comment: @leena: Answer the questions asked, _and only those_.